# Stored procedure SQL Server 2005 transaction deadlock problem

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have a problem while running sql stored procedure (MSSQL 2005). Here is the code of it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [GetItemColors]
    @FetchCount int
AS
BEGIN
SELECT 
    TOP (@FetchCount) item.Id as ItemId, item.Published as Published, attributeValue.String as Color
    FROM tblItem item, tblAttribute attributeValue, tblAttributeDefinition attributeDef
    WHERE 
        item.Id = attributeValue.fkItemId 
        AND item.Deleted = 0
        AND item.PendingPublish = 0 
        AND attributeValue.fkAttributeDefinitionId = attributeDef.Id
        AND attributeDef.[Name] = 'Color'
    ORDER BY item.Published DESC
END;
```

Some times the execution of the procedure ends with exception:

```
SqlException: Transaction (Process ID 66) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

Does anyone know how to rewrite the procedure to avoid the exception?

Is there anyway of 'pre-locking' tables within the stored procedure invocation so other code can't interrupt the execution?

Thanks in advance for you help!

---

edit 1: Estimated execution plan attached

[image: estimated execution plan]

---

edit 2: I **can't** get Deadlock Graph as the exception happens couple times per day in the live environment only. I'm not allowed to run profiler in live environment. I didn't manage to reproduce the deadlock in development environment.

---

edit 3: I didn't managed to get the deadlock winner.

Comment: It looks like a fairly normal select statement to me.  It's probably not the query, but a configuration issue.

Comment: What is it deadlocking with? Can you get the deadlock graph via SQL Profiler? What isolation level are your statements running at? Does your execution plan indicate that you might be missing some indexes?

Comment: @Martin I can't get the deadlock graph via profiler as the exception happens couple times per day in the live environment only. I've attached the screenshot of the estimated execution plan - don't think any indexes are missing here.

Comment: I beg to differ. There is not a single index seek in that plan!

Comment: You don't need to run profiler to capture the deadlock info. You can use server side traces, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293613.aspx. Running a server side trace with only the deadlock XML event enabled is the recommended way to troubleshoot deadlocks. The overhead is negligible and can be safely deployed on production servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. post the deadlock info. See [How to: Save Deadlock Graphs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190465.aspx).
2. post the statement this procedure deadlocks *with* (ie. the deadlock winner)
3. post the **exact** schema of your tables involved, including all the indexes, clustered and non-clustered

You execution plan has no less than 3 clustered index scans. With a *picture* of the plan instead of the actual plan one cannot say what are the actual properties of the operators, but those lines look quite thick (indicating large results) and they are behind parallelism operators. All these point toward a bad indexing strategy that causes table scans. Such large scans are guaranteed to conflict with *any* update. When the conflict results in a deadlock (which often happens due to index update order) then this query, as a read-only operation, will always be chosen ads a victim.

One solution is to properly index your database as to no longer have those expensive table scans. Besides overall performance benefit, it will also reduce the probability of deadlock conflict.

If deadlock persist, then the answer would be very specific depending on the actual deadlock situation.

As for a magic 'pre-lock' strategy, you can take a sledgehammer and decorate your query with or TABLOCK or even TABLOCKX hints, but the performance will go down the drain in no time. The proper solution is to address the deadlock, not to force serialization.

Comment: Also, if you use the dreaded EAV model, read this first: http://sqlcat.com/whitepapers/archive/2008/09/03/best-practices-for-semantic-data-modeling-for-performance-and-scalability.aspx

Comment: Thanks Remus for your comments. I've reexamined the indexes and I can create an additional index that will help me with the 13% percent of the execution costs that you can see on the bottom of the execution plan, however the problem seems to be with the **[attributeValue].[String]** column which is **ntext** (so I can't index this column) and despite the fact that I'm not performing any searches on it, it forces me to go through the whole table to retrieve the data...

Comment: Looks like your query hits the index tipping point (http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/category/The-Tipping-Point.aspx). You cannot INCLUDE the legacy type (`ntext`). Any chance you can change the column to a non-deprecated type, like `nvarchar(max)`?

Comment: Unfortunately this is a database lying in behind of the big CMS and I'm not able to change the column type to nvarchar. Even if I retrieve row ids first and then ask for the values for given ids, there will still be place for deadlock. Looks like the problem is **deprecated ntext type**. Good to learn something though.